# How are clauses containing adverbial clauses and free modifiers represented in syntax trees?

Tags: grammar, syntax-trees

I know that relative clauses simply go in the noun phrase containing the noun they modify, but what about adverbial clauses and free modifiers? How do you represent a clause containing an adverbial clause or a free modifier?

For example, how would you represent the sentence: "The earth, when it shook, glorified God." or the sentence: "They spoke to the king, warning him of the coming army." as syntax trees?

Comment: "When it shook" is probably best analysed as a supplementary adjunct. "Warning him of the coming army" is a modifier in clause structure - a depictive adjunct giving descriptive information about the referent of "they".